# how to put div's on equal margins

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
 <div class='row'>
     <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;float:right;'>
       <P>some data</div>
     </div>
     <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;float:right;'>
       <P>some data</div>
     </div>
     <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;float:right;'>
       <P>some data</div>
     </div>
       <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;float:right;'>
       <P>some data</div>
     </div>
     <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;float:right;'>
       <P>some data</div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Now problem is that when i make screen size small div's moves down according to screen size but at right side there are lots of black space remains i just want to make that space distributed equally  to margins  how to do this i need help

Comment: major syntax problems, check your code! you open up `p` tags and close them as `div`s it should be `<p>...</p>` not `<P>...</div>`

Comment: if you want to have responsive items you have to use percentage width not exact width with pixels and you may change floating and use display:inline-block and box-sizing:border-box instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want same size but must me equally distribute the margins and also when sereen size is less then width divs must slide down.

Flexbox can do that;

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.column {
  height: 150px;
  flex: 0 0 150px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class="column">
    <p>some data 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>some data 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>some data 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>some data 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>some data 5</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` for parent and `display-table-cell` to children to have the columns spread equally. No need for floats.

```css
.row {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.column {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;'>
    <p>some data</p>
  </div>
  <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;'>
    <p>some data</p>
  </div>
  <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;'>
    <p>some data</p>
  </div>
  <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;'>
    <p>some data</p>
  </div>
  <div class='column' style='height:150px;width:150px;'>
    <p>some data</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its Compressing Div,s I don;t to compress i want same size but must me equally distribute the margins and also when sereen size is less then width divs must slide down